# Open Google Calendar in a new tab

Tags: jsf, google-calendar-api, commandlink

I'm developing a project using java and jsf. I am trying to open Google Calendar when the user clicks on a commandLink but I have no clue about how to do it.

Does anyone knows how can I handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this link it might help 

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java

Comment: I have been already reading that, but it only shows you how to insert, get ... events and calendars. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting to an external URL in a new tab and performing an action in backing bean at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188912/redirecting-to-an-external-url-in-a-new-tab-and-performing-an-action-in-backing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like this:

```
public void goTo(){
  ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  externalContext.redirect("YOUR URL");
}
```

Comment: This opens Google Calendar in the same tab. Do you know how to do that in other one?

Comment: You must put in your commandLink the attribute target="_blank"